C# EF Core Unit Testing using Moq
I have been working on setting up unit testing with Moq for some of our CQRS commands.
I have mocked up a command handler that works in my environment to run the command.
The issue I am running into is the unit testing portion. When trying to mock the AddAsync call, I keep getting a null value for newUser in the RaiseDomainEvent function.
Here is the set up for the command and handler, basically what it is saying is if there are any settings, raise a domain event.
User / User Settings Entities -- trying to do rich domain modeling here
public class User
{
    private User(int id, string username)
    {
        UserId = id;
        UserName = username;
    }
    public int UserId {get; private set;}
    public string UserName {get; private set;}
    public List<UserSetting> UserSettings {get; private set;}

    public static User Create(int id, string username)
    {
        return new User(id, username);
    }
    public static DomainEvent RaiseDomainEvent(User user, List<UserSetting> settings)
    {
        // Raise the event and handle it
    }
}

public class UserSetting
{
    public int SettingId {get; set;}
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public int SettingTypeId {get; set;}
    public string SettingValue {get; set;}
}

Add User Command
public sealed record AddUserCommand (
    int UserId, string UserName, List<UserSetting> UserSettings
) : ICommand; 

Add User Command Handler - utilizes Mediatr
internal sealed class AddUserCommandHandler : ICommandHandler<AddUserCommand>
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private readonly IUserRepo _userRepo;

    public AddUserCommandHandler(IMapper mapper, IUserRepo userRepo)
    {
        _mapper = mapper ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mapper));
        _userRepo = userRepo ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(userRepo));
    }

    public async Task<Result> Handle(AddUserCommand cmd, CancellationToken ct = default)
    {
        User dbUser = await _userRepo.GetUserByIdAsync(cmd.UserId, ct);

        if (dbUser != null) throw new Exception($"User exists with id: {cmd.UserId}");

        User newUser = User.Create(cmd.UserId, cmd.UserName);

        // Since the id is generated on the DB add, we need to get it to add a FK relationship to add settings to it
        newUser = await _userRepo.AddAsync(newUser, ct);

        if (cmd.UserSettings != null && cmd.UserSettings.Any())
        {
            User.RaiseDomainEvent(newUser, cmd.UserSettings);
        }

        return new Result 
        {
            Success = true
        };
    }
}

Add async
public async Task<User> AddAsync(User entity, CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    _context.Users.Add(entity);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(ct);

    return entity;
}

The above code works in its actual capacity
The issue comes from when I try to unit test this.
I unit test it utilizing Moq.
public class AddUserCommandHandlerTests
{
    private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapperMock;
    private readonly Mock<IUserRepo> _userRepoMock;

    public AddUserCommandHandlerTests()
    {
        _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
        _userRepoMock = new Mock<IUserRepo>();    
    }

    // This test works!
    [Fact]
    public async Task Handle_Should_Return_SuccessResult_NoSettings()
    {
        AddUserCommand cmd = new AddUserCommand(0, "stacktest", new List<UserSetting>());

        User mockDbUser = null;

        _userRepoMock.Setup(x => x.GetUserByIdAsync(cmd.UserId, default).Result).Returns(mockDbUser);

        var handler = new AddUserCommandHandler(_mapperMock.Object, _userRepoMock.Object);

        var result = await handler.Handle(cmd, default);

        Assert.True(result.Success);
    }

    // This test fails, saying that newUser is null at User.RaiseDomainEvent(newUser, cmd.UserSettings)
    [Fact]
    public async Task Handle_Should_Return_SuccessResult_WithSettings()
    {
        AddUserCommand cmd = new AddUserCommand(0, "stacktest", new List<UserSetting> { SettingId = 0, SettingTypeId = 1, UserId = 0, SettingValue = "Test"});

        User mockDbUser = null;

        User addedDbUser = User.Create(10, cmd.UserName);

        _userRepoMock.Setup(x => x.GetUserByIdAsync(cmd.UserId, default).Result).Returns(mockDbUser);
        _userRepoMock.Setup(x => x.AddAsync(mockDbUser, default).Result).Returns(addedDbUser);

        var handler = new AddUserCommandHandler(_mapperMock.Object, _userRepoMock.Object);

        var result = await handler.Handle(cmd, default);

        Assert.True(result.Success);
    }
}

Why is the AddAsync result not being moq'd correctly?

You may try setting the Mocks to strict and then see where you get MockException in a test run that tells you what setup is wrong or you forgot. You code calls User.Create itself ignoring your mockDbUser. Hence your AddAsync setup for that is missing as mockDbUser isn't used in the actual code.

Don't use DbContext.AddAsync. It doesn't add anything, just as Add doesn't add anything. Add attaches a detached object (ie one not loaded from the database) in the Added state so SaveChanges can generate an INSERT for it when it persists ALL pending changes. AddAsync is ONLY used for rare ID generation policies like HiLo or client ranges, which need to retrieve some data from the server to calculate IDs on the client

@PanagiotisKanavos AddAsync is my function which utilizes efcore's Add(entity) and save changes async for its specific context

In that case you need to post your code, otherwise it's impossible to help.

@Ralf Did not know of strict for Mocks, I will take a look at the docs and go from there and see if I find anything

@Travis and save changes async is a critical bug that completely breaks the Unit-of-Work pattern. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work, not a connection. SaveChanges commits the Unit-of-Work which means your code may well DELETE 43 Product entities along with inserting 1 User

@PanagiotisKanavos I added my AddAsync function to the question. So you are saying in the AddAsync function I should be utilizing _context.SaveChanges instead of SaveChangesAsync?

No, I'm saying the entire idea of this CRUD pseudo-repository is wrong. It's a well known antipattern, ie bug. How are you going to roll back changes if something goes wrong? You're trying to put a high level multi-entity Unit of Work abstraction inside a low level CRUD class. ORMs like NHibernate and EF try to give the impression of working with an object database or in-memory objects instead of tables and entities.

@PanagiotisKanavos What would be some good documentation to read? I would like to refactor to avoid said antipattern... I did not know that and would definitely like to do it the proper way. Doing some googling on, I found this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application
Figured thats a place to start.

@Travis Treat each test as an isolated unit. The mocks should be created per test as your current example will cause conflicting setups to override each other depending on the order of execution.

Your setup of AddAsync is incorrect.
You are registering it to be called with mockDbUser but Handle does not call AddAsync with mockDbUser. Since the actual object used by Handle to call AddAsync is generated within Handle itself, you won't have access to it. So when Handle calls AddAsync in the unit test, it ignores your setup because the parameters don't match what you have in your setup.
You can resolve the issue by using the Moq Is methods. It.IsAny allows you to specify any argument of a given type as a parameter for a method being setup:
_userRepoMock.SetUp(x => x.AddAsync(It.IsAny<User>(), default).Result).Returns(addedDbUser);

It.Is allows you to specify any argument of a given type that meets some chosen conditions as a parameter for a method being setup e.g.:
_userRepoMock.SetUp(x => x.AddAsync(It.Is<User>(x => x.UserId == 10 && x.UserName == cmd.UserName), default).Result).Returns(addedDbUser);


Ah! That makes a lot of sense, I thought it was looking for the expected object and not looking for mockDbUser. I added this portion and the value was no longer a null result.
